# What are the names of these (possibly Korean) maths books and what are they about?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

While reading a quanta article about a mathematician (edit: [link](https://www.quantamagazine.org/secret-link-uncovered-between-pure-math-and-physics-20171201/) provided by commenter!), I came across an image of his bookshelf with these books.

Out of pure curiosity I'd love to know more about them. I believe the books are in Korean but I may be mistaken.

[image]

Comment: mostly you have every title in a numbered series if you are an editor for it.

Comment: It's from the article about Minhyong Kim: https://www.quantamagazine.org/secret-link-uncovered-between-pure-math-and-physics-20171201/.

Comment: Mmm... Matrix cookbooks? just kidding...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This book series has nothing to do with Mathematics. It is a 19 part collection of manuscripts by Professor 김우창 (Kim Uchang), Professor Emeritus at Korea University. He is a literary scholar and the text covers the Japanese colonial period, the Korean War to the era of Globalization and how it pertains to Korean literature.

You can easily find results by googling the books publisher, Minumsa Books with the author's name 김우창.

Comment: mystery solved thank you! for completeness here is a link http://minumsa.minumsa.com/book_series/%EA%B9%80%EC%9A%B0%EC%B0%BD-%EC%A0%84%EC%A7%91/